# Search for the shortest route in a turnracer game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've made a remake of the turnracer game. The goal of the game is to go to the random generated dot using as little as possible moves. The game moves with the numpad. You have to reset your own speed by countering it with speed to the other way. So if speed to the left is 2 and you choose right the dot will only move one to the left. I was wondering if anyone could help me create a system where you check what the shortest route to the random generated dot is. Thanks in advance!
live demo: http://jsbin.com/fefuhazeba/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a "shortest path" finder. There are different algorithms out there (so you don't have to reinvent the wheel by coming up with your own).

Have a look at **A* Algorithm**. It is the main algorithm used in games for path finding. It has been proved to be optimal (it always finds the shortest path) and it does not take too long to compute.

Here are some links about it:
http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm